# Jquery - Set selected option by value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried all the solutions from google.  What am I missing?  The option I want is not being selected.
Here's the section of code i'm having trouble with.  I've  included some other things I've tried (commented out).

If it matters, this list is built dynamically, but the code to select it by value is after that process.
i'm in Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149

```js
// EDIT ADDED THIS CODE FROM MY APPLICATION
const url = '/api/Customers';

// Populate dropdown
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.CustomerID).text(entry.Name + ' - ' + entry.Email));
    })
});
// END EDIT ^^^^^

//var customerID = window.location.hash;
var customerID = "6a1920b2-f388-4790-a720-75048e1407a7"; //Test User 5
console.log(customerID);

//$('#customer-dropdown option[value="'+ customerID +'"]').prop('selected', true);
//$("#customer-dropdown select").val(customerID);
$("#customer-dropdown option[data-value='" + customerID +"']").attr("selected","selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="customer-dropdown" name="c15905d7-8216-4e81-ac15-2fafd10b49e8">
 <option disabled="">Select Customer</option>
 <option value="297f8676-80bf-43e5-b463-031a5b5154aa">Test User 1</option>
 <option value="83941899-8039-488f-bf6b-0d036c7d6556">Test User 2</option>
 <option value="263356fd-d803-4436-a7fc-4df5a3095771">Test User 3</option>
 <option value="2e31ee49-b096-4237-b07e-61071871334d">Test User 4</option>
 <option value="6a1920b2-f388-4790-a720-75048e1407a7">Test User 5</option>
 <option value="072f6800-570c-4004-b9cd-7bdb4cf98b0a">Test User 6</option>
 <option value="c957f2c0-f72e-4de7-9b4f-9272cbbfd783">Test User 7</option>
 <option value="d870225f-c020-4369-bd7b-9dc5d16f34a1">Test User 8</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign the value to `select`.

```js
//var customerID = window.location.hash;
var customerID = "6a1920b2-f388-4790-a720-75048e1407a7"; //Test User 5

//$('#customer-dropdown option[value="'+ customerID +'"]').prop('selected', true);
//$("#customer-dropdown select").val(customerID);
$("#customer-dropdown").val(customerID);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="customer-dropdown" name="c15905d7-8216-4e81-ac15-2fafd10b49e8">
 <option disabled="">Select Customer</option>
 <option value="297f8676-80bf-43e5-b463-031a5b5154aa">Test User 1</option>
 <option value="83941899-8039-488f-bf6b-0d036c7d6556">Test User 2</option>
 <option value="263356fd-d803-4436-a7fc-4df5a3095771">Test User 3</option>
 <option value="2e31ee49-b096-4237-b07e-61071871334d">Test User 4</option>
 <option value="6a1920b2-f388-4790-a720-75048e1407a7">Test User 5</option>
 <option value="072f6800-570c-4004-b9cd-7bdb4cf98b0a">Test User 6</option>
 <option value="c957f2c0-f72e-4de7-9b4f-9272cbbfd783">Test User 7</option>
 <option value="d870225f-c020-4369-bd7b-9dc5d16f34a1">Test User 8</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I try that in my code and it always selects the 1st option.  I see in your test it did pick up #5.  Wonder why that's not working in my app..

Comment: Did you comment all unused codes? Note you should use `$("#customer-dropdown")` instead of `$("#customer-dropdown select")`

Comment: I edited and added the dynamic part.  I wonder if its a timing thing?  Wonder if .getJSON is async...

Comment: Google says .getJSON is async.  That's got to be my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being my solution to combat the timing issue introduced by .getJSON (async):

I just selected it as I built the dropdown:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        //console.log(entry.CustomerID + " | " + customerID + " | " + (entry.CustomerID == customerID))
        if (entry.CustomerID == customerID) {
            dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr({ value: entry.CustomerID, selected: "selected" }).text(entry.Name + ' - ' + entry.Email));
            dropdown.val(customerID);
        } else {
            dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.CustomerID).text(entry.Name + ' - ' + entry.Email));
        }
    })
});
```